# How to solve git remote end hung up unexpectedly?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-clone

The issue that I can't access a private repo. I have set SSH keys and everything.

```
Error checking out spec='custom-branch' for repo git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/fivetran-dbt-stripe.git
fatal: couldn't find remote ref custom-branch
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The code above is been initiated from a cli app which I insert the repo name into.

However, I can access git

```
[nir@dba-dev fivetran_dbt]$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

Also, git clone of `git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/fivetran-dbt-stripe.git` works.
How can I investigate the root cause of this?

[image]

Comment: Your pblm is not with the repo access but with the branch you are trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, git clone of `git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/fivetran-dbt-stripe.git` works

Then, inside the local clone, do:

```
git branch -avv
```

You will see the remote branches from that repository, and will be able to pick an actual *existing* remote branch name (since `custom-branch` does not seem to exist)